# Using both id and slug when building paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model, let's say user, with both an id and a slug.  I'd like to be able to generate a url using user_path(@user) that contains both the id and slug.

I know that user_path will use to_param method for the parameter it puts at the end of the url, but is there a way to use 2 (or more parameters) and get something like this:
http://domain.com/users/id/slug

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Friendly-id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) is a great way to generate permalinks. It also offers pretty good customization options.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this in your model?

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{slug)"
end
```

Comment: I did try this but got a RoutingError that user_path failed to generate. Any ideas? Can I provide any more details?

Comment: Whoops, my bad. The `/` should cause trouble there, use a `-` instead

Comment: If I use - instead (e.g. 1234-slug-slug) that means the whole string will be in params[:id] though and I will need to parse out the id in the controller, right?

Comment: yes but that's easy. `params[:id].to_i` will readily take care of that